# Drag a selected input box in numerical order

Tags: javascript

In my HTML ,I have a text box which contains numeric value only.Suppose in the next row I have another text box.Now what I want is when I do drag on first text box(mouse hold) ,in the next text box value will automatically incremented by 1 when I unhold the mouse.I am stuck with this and find a solution .

**Below is the code snippet what I tried:**

```js
var active = false;
var currentX;
var currentY;
var initialX;
var initialY;
var xOffset = 0;
var yOffset = 0;

if (document.getElementById("input1").value != null) {
  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);
  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);
}

function dragStart(e) {
  if (e.type === "touchstart") {
    initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - xOffset;
    initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - yOffset;
  } else {
    initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
    initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;
  }
  console.log('initialX::' + initialX + " initialY" + initialY);

  if (e.target === document.getElementById("input1")) {
    active = true;
  }
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  initialX = currentX;
  initialY = currentY;

  active = false;
}

function drag(e) {
  if (active) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.type === "touchmove") {
      currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - initialX;
      currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - initialY;
    } else {
      currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
      currentY = e.clientY - initialY;
    }
    console.log('xoffset::' + currentX);
    console.log('yoffset' + currentY);
    xOffset = currentX;
    yOffset = currentY;

    setTranslate(currentX, currentY,       document.getElementById("input1"));
  }
}

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
  el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <br>
    <input id='input1' value='1' />
    <br>
    <input id='input2' value='' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This Problem is cause due to it's event listener. you write All listener on `input` element. when mouse `drag` start then input is `moving` under same position of mouse pointer.But when we increase `Mouse Pointer` movement speed it Goes `outside` of input box.

At that time Mouse move `event not fire` because you write `drag` event on input control right ?

Solution :

1. Make one container in which input you want to drag.
2. Write `mouse move` event listener on that container

you should Try below snippet.

```js
var active = false;
var currentX;
var currentY;
var initialX;
var initialY;
var xOffset = 0;
var yOffset = 0;

if (document.getElementById("input1").value != null) {
  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("touchstart", dragStart, false);
  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("touchend", dragEnd, false);
  document.getElementById("inputContainer").addEventListener("touchmove", drag, false);
  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("mousedown", dragStart, false);
  document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("mouseup", dragEnd, false);
  document.getElementById("inputContainer").addEventListener("mousemove", drag, false);
}

function dragStart(e) {
  if (e.type === "touchstart") {
    initialX = e.touches[0].clientX - xOffset;
    initialY = e.touches[0].clientY - yOffset;
  } else {
    initialX = e.clientX - xOffset;
    initialY = e.clientY - yOffset;
  }

  if (e.target === document.getElementById("input1")) {
    active = true;
  }
}

function dragEnd(e) {
  initialX = currentX;
  initialY = currentY;

  active = false;
}

function drag(e) {

  if (active) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.type === "touchmove") {
      currentX = e.touches[0].clientX - initialX;
      currentY = e.touches[0].clientY - initialY;
    } else {
      currentX = e.clientX - initialX;
      currentY = e.clientY - initialY;
    }
    xOffset = currentX;
    yOffset = currentY;

    setTranslate(currentX, currentY, document.getElementById("input1"));
  }
}

function setTranslate(xPos, yPos, el) {
  el.style.transform = "translate3d(" + xPos + "px, " + yPos + "px, 0)";
}
```

```css
#inputContainer{
width: 100vw;
height: 100vh;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <br>
  <div id="inputContainer">
    <input id='input1' value='1' />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes I can now drag the elements and drop it another place. But my actual requirement is little different. When I call drag method from that particular column and when drop it just below under column the column value should be auto incremented.Like excel like features.

Comment: Do you want to make functionality like drag every input box into one input box and it's value is increse by dropped input box's value ?

Comment: Let me explain,Suppose I have a HTML table with two column inside it. Both the column value is in numeric in nature. Now ,If some user drag the first column value and drop it in 2nd column then the 2nd column value should be incremented by one but the first column value persist . So, the new value will be 1 and 2 for the two columns respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly then , this is a clean solution

```html
  <br>
  <!--mouseup event-->
  <input onmouseup="mouseUp()" id='input1' value='1' />
  <br>
  <input id='input2' value='2' />
  <script>
  //mouseup function
  function mouseUp() {
  //get input value from inputs
      var a = document.getElementById('input1').value;
      var b = document.getElementById('input2').value;
      //add them to second input
      document.getElementById('input2').value= +a + +b;
    }
    
  </script>
```

Comment: This is not what I exactly wanted. Like excel we can drag from an column and when drop it was incremented the column value . SO ,I want to implement similar kind of approach using javascript. AT first the page is load and when I placed mouse hold(drag),then the column value is auto incremented when I drop the mouse hold.